# > System.ArgumentNullException: ''column' argument cannot be null. Parameter name: column' when trying to do parent child combobox with a database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am struggling to get some code working that has been shown to me in the previous question. I am quite new to vb.net and database programming so I don't quite know how to get it to work. The code I am trying to do is in this link https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?518065 . I need the user input to the parent combo box to then change the data in the child Combo box. Here is what I got so far if anyone could point me in the right direction, I really need to get this to work somehow

Edit: After changing the code according to your comments I am getting this error message :

> System.ArgumentNullException: ''column' argument cannot be null.
> Parameter name: column'

```
      Dim data As DataSet = Me.GetDataSet()


    Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = data
    Me.BindingSource1.DataMember = "RoomType"

    Me.BindingSource2.DataSource = Me.BindingSource1
    Me.BindingSource2.DataMember = "Rooms"

    Me.cmbRoomType.DisplayMember = "roomtype.RoomTypeName"
    Me.cmbRoomType.ValueMember = "roomtype.RoomTypeID"
    Me.cmbRoomType.DataSource = Me.BindingSource1

    Me.cmbRoomNumber.DisplayMember = "roomsRoomNumber"
    Me.cmbRoomNumber.ValueMember = "rooms.RoomID"
    Me.cmbRoomNumber.DataSource = Me.BindingSource2



End Sub
Private ConStr As String = "Data Source=dbNEAProject.db"

Private Function GetDataSet() As DataSet
    Dim data As New DataSet
    Dim parent As DataTable = Me.GetRoomType()
    Dim child As DataTable = Me.GetRoomNumber()


    data.Tables.Add(parent)
    data.Tables.Add(child)
    data.Relations.Add("Rooms",
                           parent.Columns("roomtype.RoomTypeID"),
                           child.Columns("Rooms.rRoomTypeID"))
    Return data
End Function
Private Function GetRoomType() As DataTable
    Dim sql As String = "Select RoomTypeName, RoomTypeID FROM RoomType"
    Dim table As New DataTable("RoomType")
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr)
        con.Open()
        Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, con)
            da.Fill(table)

        End Using
    End Using
    Return table
End Function

Private Function GetRoomNumber() As DataTable
    Dim sql As String = "Select RoomNumber, RoomID, rRoomTypeID FROM Rooms INNER JOIN roomtype ON roomtype.roomtypeid = rooms.rroomtypeid ;"
    Dim table As New DataTable("RoomNumber")
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr)
        con.Open()
        Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, con)
            da.Fill(table)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return table
End Function
```

My sqltables in which I then need to insert chosen data:

CREATE TABLE BookedRooms(
brBookingID INTEGER,
brRoomID INTEGER,
Status VARCHAR (50) NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (brBookingID) REFERENCES Booking(BookingID),
FOREIGN KEY (brRoomID) REFERENCES Rooms(RoomID)
);

```
CREATE TABLE RoomType(
```

RoomTypeID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,
RoomTypeName VARCHAR(50),
Capacity INTEGER,
RoomPrice REAL
);

```
CREATE TABLE Rooms(
```

RoomID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
RoomNumber INTEGER,
Ensuite VARCHAR (10),
rRoomTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (rRoomTypeID) REFERENCES RoomType(RoomTypeID)
);

Comment: Firstly, why are you doing anything related to the `ComboBoxes` in the `GetParentTable` and `GetChildTable` methods? Does the original code do that? No it doesn't. All it does is create a `DataTable`, populate it and return it. Why are you doing something different? Not only that, you're not supposed to be binding the `DataTables` directly to the controls anyway. If you read the comments in the code then you know the steps: get that `DataSet` contain the tables and the relation, bind the `BindingSources` and then bind the `ComboBoxes. Do that.

Comment: All you need to do is start with the exact code I provided for you, change the `GetParentTable` and `GetChildTable` methods to populate the `DataTables` from the database instead of manually and then change the table and column names. You'll also need to have added two `BindingSources` to the form in the designer, which you should name like you did the `ComboBoxes`, and then use the appropriate names for them too.

Comment: Don't post long code snippets in comments. They are barely readable. If you have more information to provide, update your question accordingly. That said, if you check the signature under any of my posts in that thread you'll find a link to all my CodeBank threads, including code examples of using ADO.NET to retrieve and save data. It might be worth your while to check that out. Having said that, I see a call to the `Fill` method of a data adapter in that code, so it looks promising.

Comment: Hi there i wanted to ask about last few lines of your code where you `'Add a relationship between the ID of the parent 'table and the ParentID of the child table.`  how would i implement it with a database.

Comment: There's the database itself, with its schema, and then there's your software that accesses the database.  First you need to map out your schema that defines the table relationships, then you can code for it.  Research ER diagrams.

Comment: Again you are trying to create a problem where there is none. The database is irrelevant. You retrieve the data from the database into the `DataTables` and that is the end of the database's involvement. The `DataRelation` is created in the `DataSet` between the two `DataTables`. You do it EXACTLY the same way as I have done it in my code because you are doing exactly the same thing. The ONLY thing that changes is the names of the tables and columns.

Comment: Based on your code, the issue is that you're not actually retrieving the foreign key column for the child table. `RoomType` is the parent table and `RoomTypeID` is the primary key. `Rooms` is the child table so it must contain a foreign key column that contains values from `RoomType.RoomTypeID`. The obvious name for that column is also `RoomTypeID`, but you've prefixed it with an extra "r" for some reason. Once you've populated the `DataTables`, you need to create the relation between the two `RoomType.RoomTypeID` and `Rooms.rRoomTypeID` columns.

Comment: By the way, why are you using a singular name for `RoomType` and a plural name for `Rooms`? Inconsistency is always bad. I prefer singular names for tables but many people prefer plural names. Decide which one you prefer and use it EVERY time. DO NOT mix and match.